# Aggregate data based on fixed moving date window in Presto

Tags: sql, aggregate-functions, window-functions, presto

I wanted to:

1. aggregate numbers in a “3-months" rolling window, (eg Jan-Mar, Feb-Apr, Mar-May....)
2. then compare the same country & city with last year's same rolling window

Table I already have: (unique at: country + city + month level)

```
country    city     month       sum
US         A        2019-03-01  3
US         B        2019-03-01  4
DE         C        2019-03-01  5
US         A        2019-03-01  3
CN         B        2019-03-01  4
US         B        2019-04-01  4
UK         C        2019-04-01  7
US         C        2019-04-01  2
....
US         A        2019-12-01  10
US         B        2020-12-01  6
US         C        2021-01-01  7
```

Step 1 ideal output:

```
country    city     period                     sum
US         A        2019-03-01～2019-05-01      XXX
US         A        2019-04-01～2019-06-01      YYY
UK         A        2019-03-01～2019-05-01      ZZZ
...
UK         A        2020-12-01～2021-02-01      BBB
```

Step 2 ideal output:

```
country    city     period                     sum    last_year_sum   year_over_year_%
US         A        2019-03-01～2019-05-01      XXX    111              40%
US         A        2019-04-01～2019-06-01      YYY    1111             30%
UK         A        2019-03-01～2019-05-01      ZZZ    11111            20%
...
UK         A        2020-12-01～2021-02-01      BBB    1111             15%
```

Ideally, I wanted to achieve this in Presto - any idea how to do that? Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Presto doesn't support the `range` window frame specification using dates.  One method uses joins and aggregation and then `lag()` to get the last year amount:

```
select t.country, t.city, t.sum,
       sum(t2.sum) as this_year_sum,
       lag(sum(t2.sum), 12) over (partition by country, city order by month) as prev_year_sum,
       (-1 + 
        sum(t2.sum) /
        lag(sum(t2.sum), 12) over (partition by country, city order by month)
       ) as yoy_increase
from t left join
     t t2
     on t2.country = t.country and
        t2.city = t.city and
        t2.month >= t.month and
        t2.month <= t.month + interval '2' month
group by t.country, t.city, t.sum;
```

Note:  This assumes that you have data for all months for each `country`/`city` combination.